# Custom css toggle switch align issue in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have custom toggle switch inside a table. I want them vertically and horizontally centered in the cell. While they are appearing as intended in Chrome and Safari, they are slightly shifted down on firefox. A solution or a better way to implement this is much appreciated. Below is my html and css codes:

```css
html
{
  font-size: 15px;
  
}

input[type=checkbox]{
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.checkboxcell {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.66rem;
}

.toggle + label {
    cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
    height: 1.6rem;
    background: #DD7E6B;
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    position: relative;
  top: -1.15rem;
}

.toggle:checked + label {
    background: #2ECC71;
}

.toggle + label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.3rem;
    left: 0.3rem;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    background: steelblue;
    border-radius: 6rem;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.toggle:checked + label:after {
    left: calc(100% - 0.3rem);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<html>
  
<table width="50%" cellpadding="2" border="1" cellspacing="0"><tr align="center"><th colspan="2">Access Status</th></tr>
       <tr align="center"><th width="50%">Workload</th><th>Time Table</th></tr>
       <tr align="center"><th><div class="checkboxcell"><input type="checkbox" class="toggle" checked/><label></label></div></th>
       <th><div class="checkboxcell">
         <input type="checkbox" class="toggle"/><label></label>
       </div></th></tr>
       <tr align="center" height="25"><th colspan="2"></th></tr></table>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
align-items: center;
display: flex;
```

for your divs and remove:

```
top: -1.15rem;
```

from the label.

```css
html
{
    font-size: 15px;

}

input[type=checkbox]{
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.checkboxcell {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.66rem;
}

.toggle + label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.6rem;
    background: #DD7E6B;
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    position: relative;
}

.toggle:checked + label {
    background: #2ECC71;
}

.toggle + label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.3rem;
    left: 0.3rem;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    background: steelblue;
    border-radius: 6rem;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.toggle:checked + label:after {
    left: calc(100% - 0.3rem);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<table width="50%" cellpadding="2" border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr align="center">
        <th colspan="2">Access Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <th width="50%">Workload</th>
        <th>Time Table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <th>
            <div class="checkboxcell"><input type="checkbox" class="toggle" checked/><label></label></div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="checkboxcell">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle"/><label></label>
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" height="25">
        <th colspan="2"></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This solves vertical alignment but mess up horizontal alignment. It is subtle in Chrome but significant in Firefox.

Comment: @ParthaS.Pal Answer updated. Now the checkboxes have an absolute position. Let me know

Comment: Absolutely genius. I can't thank you enough.